# Spring boot and rabbitmq integration, how to recover on component failure?

Tags: spring, design-patterns, rabbitmq, integration, messaging

I have a spring rest app with rabbit as messaging middle ware. When the app accepts incoming rest request, it replies to the user meanwhile it does some extra processing asynchronously, generates a new message and puts it on rabbit. From there, some consumers read the message and deliver it to the external system. Now, there is a case that the rabbit server itself may be down.
To handle that kind of failure, I have a blocking queue (of course with an adjustable size)

```
 @Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(25);

    return executor;
}
```

The queue will be able to handle some messages until rabbit comes online. But if it takes too long and the requests exceeds the queue size, then it is going to fail. Now the question is, are there a ways that I can improve this and make it more efficient? What is the industry best practice? Are there any patterns for that scenario?

Comment: Perhaps Spring Cloud Histrix Circuit breaker.  https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html  or https://spring.io/guides/gs/circuit-breaker/

Comment: So probably it makes sense to wrap both consumers and producers in Histrix breaker. What about rabbit connection factory itself? If it can't establish a connection, it does not make sense to retry it over and over and waste the network and server resources.

Comment: The Spring cloud Stream Binder  http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_spring_cloud_stream  introduces the concepts of persistent publish-subscribe semantics. By default, the RabbitMQ binder uses Spring Boot’s ConnectionFactory, and it therefore supports all Spring Boot configuration options for RabbitMQ.  But, in my humble opinion, if you are new to Spring cloud, follow this excellent course first : https://www.udemy.com/microservices-with-spring-cloud/learn/v4/overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used spring retryable. That is pretty much sufficient for the requirement. As I can retry, configure retry intervals, max attempts etc. as well as implement custom recover function.

```
   @Async
    @Retryable(value = { AmqpException.class },
            maxAttempts=10, backoff=@Backoff(delay=100, maxDelay=300000,multiplier = 2))
    public void sendEmailMessageToQueue(SimpleMailMessage email){
        log.info("Sending message to queue"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, email);
        }catch (AmqpException e){
            log.log(Level.WARNING,"Could not send message to queue, will retry.",e);
        }
    }

    @Recover
    public void connectionException(AmqpException e) {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE,"Could not send message to queue, will save the message in db instead."+Thread.currentThread().getName(),e);
    }
```